# Shutil raises OSError

Tags: python-3.x, shutil, oserror

In my webscraping project I collect different types of data from the internet, which are added to an excel file.
Until recently, my back up method of this excel file consisted of copying it to a different folder, using Shutil. I updated the script in a more proper way so that the filename includes the corresponding year and month too.

- Example of original file: data.xlsx
- Name of backup file: 2021-03_data.xlsx

No magic whatsoever, but ever since, the script raises an OS Error, stating that the operation is not supported. Interestingly, the file is copied perfectly...  But the error bugs me since it breaks the script and does not execute what follows.

This is the code:

```
#Export to Excel
final_df.to_excel(last_search, index=False)
#Backup
yearBackup = str(datetime.now().year)
monthBackup = str('{:02d}'.format(datetime.now().month)) #2 digits
pathBackup = Path(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'backup' , f'{yearBackup}-{monthBackup}_data.xlsx') 
shutil.copy(last_search, pathBackup)
```

The error message refers to line 146:

```
shutil.copy(last_search, pathBackup)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=snowserver,share=home/Drive/Drive/Python/Webscraping/projects/online/online-data.py", line 146, in <module>
    shutil.copy(last_search, pathBackup)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 416, in copy
    copymode(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 305, in copymode
    chmod_func(dst, stat.S_IMODE(st.st_mode))
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported: '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=snowserver,share=home/Drive/Drive/Python/Webscraping/projects/online/backup/2021-03_data.xlsx'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Linux filenames can't have forward slashes in them. I'm surprised that you can have such a python file to begin with.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same error when trying to `shutil.copy()` a file to an Android device (which is connected via MTP, i.e. mounted via GVfs like your Samba share). Looks like this is a bug in `shutil.copymode()` which apparently cannot handle GVfs partitions.

Comment: @StarDust Where do you see a forward slash in a file *name* (not file *path*)?